# Mutable Object safe publication with one only one thread writing

Tags: java, concurrency

Let non-threadsafe, mutable object `X` be constructed in thread `A`.  `A` passes `X`, post construction, to thread `B`.  `B` mutates `X` and `A` never accesses `X` again.

Will the state of `X` always be properly visible to `B`?

Is `X` effectively thread confined?

My reading of *Java Concurrency in Practice* seems to indicate that `X` is not properly published but I cannot cause any problems for thread `B` in test rigs that run millions of replications. I suspect this is just dumb luck.

For background, `X` represents a multitude of complex classes over which I have no control that are authored by modelers who have only a basic knowledge of Java.  It is strongly preferred that `X` has no synchronized blocks or other concurrency mechanisms or requirements.

I am currently solving this problem by having thread `A` pass a thread-safe factory for `X` that `B` invokes, thus making `X` thread confined.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how `A` passes `X` to `B`?

Comment: A collection of X is passed to a utility class that submits a Callable C for each X to a completion service.  Each X is passed into the callable's constructor.  The callable then performs numerous mutations on X.

Comment: You mean an `ExecutorService`? Then you should be fine: [*Memory consistency effects: Actions in a thread prior to the submission of a `Runnable` or `Callable` task to an `ExecutorService` happen-before any actions taken by that task*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)

Comment: A CompletionService wraps an ExecutorService so it seems that the happens-before is guaranteed. Thanks.

Comment: *I suspect this is just dumb luck.* Not necessarily. Just because some behavior isn't guaranteed by the spec, doesn't mean you won't be able to consistently reproduce it. But it could theoretically break with any trivial change to the code, compiler, runtime, OS, processor etc.

Comment: BTW, attempting to empirically test and demonstrate thread safety issues may be impossible on architectures that have stronger memory consistency guarantees than the JVM. Unsafe code may run fine on x86 but blow up on ARM.  (In theory, anyway.)

Comment: Which is why I did not trust my results. To recap: An object X does not have to implement any of the safe publication idioms(such as immutability) under the following scenario -- Thread A creates X, Thread A passes X to a Callable C and submits C to an ExecuterService. When the service completes C, X is now fully visible to A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Publication only safe for final fields**

The Java Memory Model doesn't guarantee that the object `X` will be completely published (fully constructed) to thread `A`.

To ensure that, you would need to make it immutable (all member fields final) or synchronize.
Quoting [`JSR-133`](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr133.pdf):

> The semantics of final fields have been strengthened to allow for thread-safe immutatability
>   without explicit synchronization. This may require steps such as store-store barriers at the
>   end of constructors in which final fields are set.

Only thing you need to avoid is leaking fields out of the class before the constructor finishes.

**Testing**

`jcstress` has in fact a sample project to demonstrate consequences of racing during publication: [JMMSample_06_Finals.java](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jcstress/file/6a9ce3b8ccc4/jcstress-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jcstress/samples/JMMSample_06_Finals.java)

Note that some efforts had to be done to replicate the problem, like using many fields. 
The implementation of the JMM depends naturally on the particular JRE that you are using and also the effects of memory barriers being used depend on the hardware being used.

On my hardware using Oracle JDK 8 I'm not able to reproduce unsafe publication using the sample with `jcstress`.

**Synchronizing**

There is a "happens-before" relationship between all synchronization actions. This is known as the *synchronization order*. Basically when you use any synchronization mechanism, you have the guarantee that actions before it will be visible after it.

As concluded in the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5):

> If a program is correctly synchronized, then all executions of the program will appear to be sequentially consistent

**In practice**

In practice it's very hard to run into problems due to actions taken in a constructor not being visible by threads using the object.
A primary reason is the usage of synchronization mechanisms. You can check some of the actions that will ensure the happens-before relationship in the javadoc: [Memory Visibility](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility)

Also as I mentioned with the `jcstress` sample, JRE nowadays seems to be very good in ensuring consistent results even when it doesn't need to according to the language specification.